# jquery mobile change to the next and previous data-role=page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Im working with jquery mobile in my project and what i trying to do instead to use the swipe effect, use two button to change to the next and to the previous data-role=page.

im trying with this javascript but i dont know why isn't working

thx for any help.

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer" data-fullscreen="true">                  
 <a href="#prvbutton" id="goback" data-icon="arrow-l" style="margin-right:340px" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Página Anterior</a>
<a href="#nextbutton" id="goforward" data-icon="arrow-r" style="margin-right:290px" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Próxima Página</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
.....something......
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="p2">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer" data-fullscreen="true">                  
 <a href="#prvbutton" data-icon="arrow-l" style="margin-right:340px" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Página Anterior</a>
<a href="#nextbutton" data-icon="arrow-r" style="margin-right:290px" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Próxima Página</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
.....something......
</div>
</div>
```

and so on........

**Javascript:**

```
$("#nextbutton").on('click', '#goforward', function () {
 var next = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
 $.mobile.changePage(next, {
    transition: 'slide'
 });
});

// Previous page
$("#prvbutton").on('click', '#goback', function () {
 var prev = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
 $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
    transition: 'slide',
    reverse: true
 });
});
```

Comment: There is no ID `nextbutton` or `prvbutton`, either change your HTML or your JavaScript selectors.

Comment: Plus I can't spot the `prev` and `next` classes

Comment: @Kilian:  thx for the tip... i have add an id for the buttons and have updated the code above... take a look pls

Comment: try changing it to this `$(document).on('click', '#goforward', function ()...`

Comment: yep.... had the same ideia now and i have tested .. works fine...  thx for the help..

Comment: write an answer with your solution... and i accept it

Comment: this is my code ;) you also you need to check if there is a prev/next page before you navigate. otherwise, your code will stop working.

Comment: @Omar:  i have seen this code in other question and have try to put it working for my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given is correct, however, you need first to check whether there is an existing page before or after the active page. Because if you call `$.mobile.changePage()` on `undefined` value, both buttons will stop working.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YMTzU/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '#goforward', function () {
  if ($.mobile.activePage.next('.ui-page').length !== 0) {
   var next = $.mobile.activePage.next('.ui-page');
   $.mobile.changePage(next, {
       transition: 'slide'
   });
  } 
});

$(document).on('click', '#goback', function () {
  if ($.mobile.activePage.prev('.ui-page').length !== 0) {
   var prev = $.mobile.activePage.prev('.ui-page');
   $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
       transition: 'slide',
       reverse: true
   });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The selectors you are using are wrong, you mixed the `href` with the `id`. Change your selectors to match your HTML code.

```
$(document).on('click', '#goforward', function () {
    var next = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
    $.mobile.changePage(next, {
        transition: 'slide'
    });
});

// Previous page
$(document).on('click', '#goback', function () {
    var prev = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
    $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
        transition: 'slide',
        reverse: true
    });
});
```