# Adding buttons to fire right/left swipe on jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

**UPDATED:** Added working code based on Omar/user2232273's suggestions.

I am working on making a desktop version of a jQuery mobile site and I am adding in navigational arrows to fire the swipe left/right functions. I am having a bit of trouble getting the Javascript to collect the correct attributes.

Here is the working javascript for the swipe left/right functions:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "[data-role='page']", function () {
    var page = "#" + $(this).attr("id");

    $(document).on("swipeleft", page, function () {
        next = $(this).jqmData("next");
        console.log(next);
        if (next) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#" + next, { transition: "slide" });
        }
    });

    $(document).on("swiperight", page, function () {
        prev = $(this).jqmData("prev");
        if (prev) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#" + prev, { transition: "slide", reverse: true });
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the updated code with working solution:

```
$(document).on('click', '.right', function (event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if ($.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]').length !== 0) {
        var next = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
        $.mobile.changePage("#" + next, {
            transition: 'slide'
        });
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.left', function (event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if ($.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]').length !== 0) {
        var prev = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
        $.mobile.changePage("#" + prev, {
            transition: 'slide',
            reverse: true
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a sample of what the page code looks like:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-next="page2">
    <div class="slide" data-role="content">
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
            <div class="content">
            LOREM IPSUM
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: All pages are present in DOM?

Comment: Yep, it's a single-page site that has 5 "page" divs(#page1, #page2, etc) using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546576/jquery-mobile-change-to-the-next-and-previous-data-role-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

**Script:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#goforward', function () {
 var next = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
 $.mobile.changePage(next, {
    transition: 'slide'
 });
});

// Previous page
$(document).on('click', '#goback', function () {
 var prev = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
 $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
    transition: 'slide',
    reverse: true
 });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<a href="#goback" data-icon="arrow-l" id="goback" class="ui-btn-left" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
<a href="#goforward" data-icon="arrow-r" id="goforward" class="ui-btn-left" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Next</a>
```

**UPDATED:**

Take a look to my working **DEMO**: [LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eEKzh/)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working somewhat, however, the next and previous functions seem to fire multiple times once I get to the 2nd page. If I click "next" on #page1, it takes me to #page2, but then if I hit "next" on #page2 it takes me to #page3 and then immediately to #page4, then it starts acting really weird after that.

Comment: Alright, I added event.stopImmediatePropagation(); which solved the issue where the functions were firing multiple times and now it is working. Thanks again!